# Java Hibernate Error "Specified JDBC Driver com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver class not found"

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

i got error when run my application, the error is:

> Specified JDBC Driver com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver class not found

my souce:
pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-convention-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.20</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-rest-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.20</version>
    </dependency> 

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
        <classifier>tests</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.CR2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/src/main/lib/sqljdbc4.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<hibernate-configuration>     
<session-factory> 

 <!-- Database connection settings -->  
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>  
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://.;database=db</property>  
    <property name="connection.username">sa</property>  
    <property name="connection.password">12345</property>   
    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>   
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2005Dialect</property>   
    <property name="show_sql">false</property>   
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>  

    <!-- Mapping files --> 
    <mapping resource="employee.hbm.xml"/> 

</session-factory>
```

code that call Hibernate:

```
public static List<Employee> SelectAll(){ 
    Configuration cfg = new Configuration();  
    cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
    SessionFactory factory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();  
    Session session = factory.openSession(); 

    //String sql_query= "from Employee where Name = 'Kevin'";
    String sql_query= "from Employee";
    Query query = session.createQuery(sql_query);
    List<Employee> employees = query.list();

    session.close();  
    factory.close(); 
    return employees;
}
```

Anyone know why?
the error happened in
SessionFactory factory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();

Directory in:

[image]

When i check the library, it Has SQLServerDriver

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Lumanyun you're using a jar that don't exist in repository Maven :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/sqljdbc4.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

Go check [here](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Csqljdbc4) a version that can helps you

Comment: i dont know whats wrong my dependency is... but with this it can running correctly... thanks bro!

Answer (score 2):

It is because of there is not `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver` in the class path.

Please, check `sqljdbc4.jar` in the class path and check `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver` class inside of the `sqljdbc4.jar`.

To find is any jar in the class path with `SQLServerDriver`, try to execute this code before the Hibernate configuration code.

```
URL driverUrl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
    .getResource(
    "com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerDriver.class");
System.out.println(driverUrl);
```

Comment: hi,,, it has SQLServerDriver  in class path...
is there any problem in Maven? because before i using sqljdbc4.jar without maven and its  doing fine

Comment: i already try driverURL, the error is same... i try import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver and it can... :<

Comment: @Lumanyun Which path do you see with `System.out.println(driverUrl);`?

Comment: dirverUrl return error Specified JDBC Driver com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver class not found

Answer (score 1):

Please check your classpath.  The driver jar must be on the classpath.  This issue is related to java not able to find the class in the specified classpath.  Put the jar file in the same directory or make it findable.

Comment: hi,,, it has SQLServerDriver  in class path...
is there any problem in Maven? because before i using sqljdbc4.jar without maven and its  doing fine

Answer (score 1):

As already said in above comments that first you check that either the class is there in classpath or not. Because as per the exception it seems that class file is missing in classpath.

Other than this Here I want to point out something different. As per the convention, you should have to use property name inside hibernate.cfg.xml file as `hibernate.connection.driver_class`, `hibernate.connection.url`, etc. 
Here You have used only connection.driver_class, connection.url, etc.

Comment: hi,,, it has SQLServerDriver  in class path...
is there any problem in Maven? because before i using sqljdbc4.jar without maven and its  doing fine

Comment: Using `hibernate` prefix in the `hibernate.cfg.xml` is not mandatory (unlike `hibernate.properties`), but it is a good style, of course.