# Error on connecting to Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, runtime-error

I have a problem in hibernate connection. In my hibernate.cfg.xml file is like below

[image]

And i get this error

[image]

Comment: JDBC driver is not available in classpath.

Comment: i have already included JDBC class path but it doesn't working

Comment: Is your Database's SID `xe'?

Comment: how can we see that our SID in database @NeerajJain

Answer (score 1):

Please use

```
hibernate.connection.driver_class
```

in place of

```
hibernate.connection.Driver_Class
```

Also try to use

`Oracle9iDialect` or `Oracle10gDialect`

Also, you can't get Oracle driver from the usual Maven repository

**How to start solve such tasks yourself**

1. Check that copy of updated `hibernate.cfg.xml` is located near compiled classes.
2. Check that inside Oracle driver jar you have this path and class `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver`
3. Check that you really has class `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver` in the classpath using this approach:
   https://stackoverflow.com/a/36278463/3405171

Comment: I'm using Oracle11g

Comment: @naveen I don't think that dialect is the reason. You can use any of them, for example `Oracle10gDialect`. I update my answer.